# Mybatis selecting list of fields with type clob

Tags: java, spring, oracle, mybatis

Spring application with mybatis for mapping.
In our database we have column `content`, type of the column is  `clob`. When getting a list of 5 rows,  `(number)id, (varchar)title, (clob)content` the problem occurs, instead of getting `content` as a String, we are getting something like `oracle.sql.CLOB@2340829`.

Model properties are: `int id, String title, String content`.

Setting specific `jdbcType` for content column like so : `<result property="content" column="content" jdbcType="CLOB" javaType="java.lang.String" />` didn't help.

The interesting thing is, when selecting single row, content retrieved as a String correctly.

Is there a way in mybatis to specify jdbcType inside of query for example `select content(jdbcType=CLOB) from table`

Comment: In `<result ...>` tag can you try with `javaType="java.sql.Clob"` type?

Comment: Sure, just one question, do I need to change type of model property too ?

Comment: it didn't work :(, Thanks for helping